# Permanently disable power management for trackpad (using Powershell or WMIC)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, touchpad, power-management, dell-xps

I kept having a problem with my Dell XPS 15 going into a sleep state (disabling the display) when my computer was left unattended for more than 10 minutes. When the system resumed, the touchpad would not work properly. I first thought it was a hardware issue but I found that shutting the lid down momentarily and lifting it up again would resolve the immediate problem so I figured that it was a software/driver issue. However, updating firmware and drivers did not resolve the problem.

Other users [reported the same issue](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-TouchPad-ClickPad-Intermittent-Problems-Possible/td-p/7762060) but I found this solution (originally from [Dell XPS 15 7590 trackpad doesn't function well after sleep/screen turn off - r/Dell](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/ijqza5/dell_xps_15_7590_trackpad_doesnt_function_well/)) worked for me:

> 1. Open the **Device Manager**.
> 2. Under *System devices*, open *Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller - A369*.
> 3. In the *Power Management* tab, uncheck “Allow computer to turn off this device to save power”.

Unfortunately, every time Windows 10 updates itself (around once a week), the power management settings are restored to their default settings. The problem returns and I have to repeat the above steps. Is there a PowerShell command – or even a WMIC command – that I could use to automate this (e.g., run every time the computer boots)?

Typing `Get-Help power` returns the following results but they are only applicable to network or storage devices:

```
Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
Enable-NetAdapterPowerManagement  Function  NetAdapter                …
Set-NetAdapterPowerManagement     Function  NetAdapter                …
Get-NetAdapterPowerManagement     Function  NetAdapter                …
Disable-NetAdapterPowerManagement Function  NetAdapter                …
Enable-StorageEnclosurePower      Function  Storage                   …
Disable-StorageEnclosurePower     Function  Storage                   …
```

Likewise, Internet searches only return results applicable to network adapters.

Note: I could avoid this problem by configuring the power management to never turn off the display but for environmental and practical reasons, I would prefer to keep this setting.

Comment: You might be able to apply [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/power-management-on-network-adapter) provided you can figure out which control class key is connected to `Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller`.  Samsung suggests this behavior is caused by a driver [conflict](https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/computing/the-touchpad-doesnt-work-when-restoring-after-system-image-backup/).  There should be tools you can use to backup the current driver, follow the advice, then install the Dell driver.

Comment: As @Ramhound's citation suggests, you can also save as a .reg file those settings, and just reapply the .reg file after a Windows Update messes up the settings.

Comment: Thanks for the useful links @Ramhound. Thanks also, DrMoishe Pippik for the useful suggestion. I'll check them out tomorrow when I'm less tired.

Comment: I would supply key if I knew it but I don’t know how to find it and I am also only guessing that device would be there.  Hence the driver solution might be a better idea